# Masters Research Paper Survey 

Tags: survey, binaural, stereo, masters-degree, research

Hi guys,

I'm currently studying my Masters in Sound for the Moving Image at the Glasgow School of Art in Scotland.  I'm doing a research paper into the commercialization of ambisonics in existing cinemas and would love if you could take 10 mins to compete this survey for my paper.

Just follow the link below to start.

http://www.surveymonkey.com/s/6XYC2LW

Note: Please have headphones handy before you begin.

Any other thoughts you wish to add after taking the survey would be great! 
Thanks, Gillian

Answer (score 0):

Done! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just finished and good luck, seems like an interesting thesis.  My only question was in regards to the recording process...it seemed like there was very little spacialization in the stereo recordings like you were using an X/Y pattern versus an ORTF which would give you greater spacialization.  SFX recordings are often done in M/S or even mono so they can be panned in the mix, but ambiances (which is basically what you were doing) are usually done in ORTF, spaced pairs, double-ORTF, or OCT.  The jump from stereo to binaural was so great I was just interested in the techniques used.  Thanks very much and again, good luck...it is great that there is research being actively done in this field.